GCP Cloud run: Connection Reset by peer
We are running a web service with the structure of

Client (Web, App) <-> AWS API Gateway <-> GCP Cloud Run Server (called by public URL)

The following error occurs when proxying a request from the API Gateway to the GCP Cloud Run, which is logged in the AWS log.

'Execution failed due to a network error communicating with endpoint: Connection reset by peer'

Not long after starting proxy the request (within 500ms), the message is logged and the API Gateway returns a Http 504 response to the Client App.
I think it is not a timeout-related problem because it generated the error in 0.5 seconds. And this happens intensively at a very specific time.
As far as I know, the 'Connection reset by peer' error is related to the socket queue size of the server, what can I do to solve the problem in Cloud Run?
Or if the cause of the problem is different from what I thought, I would appreciate it if you could let me know the cause.
We look forward to discovering the cause and resolving the problem.
